# Sub VI connector for different cluster types

Tags: labview

I want to program an API to generate JSON files.
The standard Labview VI "Flatten to Json" has the connector "anything" which I also want to use.
How is that possible?

https://www.ni.com/docs/de-DE/bundle/labview-2020/page/glang/flatten_to_json.html

[image: Anything Connector]

Comment: That "anything" input is Variant data type. One could convert any LabVIEW data type into variant, and then convert variant to any data type.

Answer (score 4):

Use the existing JSONText library found in LV2019 and later. The subVIs therein are malleable VIs that do exactly what you're requesting. If for some reason you don't like how they work, they're open source and editable.